# Creating an array of strings from preprocessor tokens

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, c++03, boost-preprocessor

I've got a list of tokens from which I'd like to create an enum (trivial) and an array of strings (to be later used to create a map of string to enum). Here's my attempt:

```
#define TOKEN_LIST  CUBE , SPHERE , CIRCLE
#define CREATE_ARRAY_OF_STRINGS( ... )  const char* token[] = { __VA_ARGS__ };  

CREATE_ARRAY_OF_STRINGS( TOKEN_LIST )
// enum SHAPE_TYPE{ TOKEN_LIST }; // easy

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 1;
}
```

The problem is that the `TOKEN_LIST` is not stringified as shown when I compile with the `-E` flag as follows:

```
const char* token[] = { CUBE , SPHERE , CIRCLE };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 1;
}
```

Where `const char* token[] = { CUBE , SPHERE , CIRCLE };` should be `const char* token[] = { "CUBE" , "SPHERE" , "CIRCLE" };`

Is there any  other way to achieve this with C++03? Boost Processor perhaps?

Comment: Why you need this?
If you use macro, that means you know before the code starts executing. So you can store them in variables instead. And use to create array or directly use them in array initialization.

Comment: In order to automatically update a map of strings to enums. I'd like to register tokens at just one point and automatically update the enum list and map. But this is not the part that I need help with.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to change the format of your `TOKEN_LIST` somewhat, you can easily do this with [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

Here's an example of using a Boost.Preprocessor *sequence* instead of a comma-separated list:

```
#define GENERATE_STRING(maZ, maIdx, maTokens) \
  BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(maIdx, maTokens))

#define GENERATE_STRINGS(maTokens) \
  BOOST_PP_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(maTokens), GENERATE_STRING, maTokens)

#define TOKEN_LIST (CUBE)(SPHERE)(CIRCLE)

const char* token[] = { GENERATE_STRINGS(TOKEN_LIST) }

enum ShapeType {
  BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(TOKEN_LIST)
};
```

Since you seem to have access to `...` and `__VA_ARGS__` (which are *not* a C++03 feature), you should be able to use a Boost.Preprocessor *tuple* as well (comma-delimited list enclosed in parentheses); with support for variadic macros, Boost.Preprocessor is capable of determining tuple size implicitly. However, I have no experience with that, so I cannot provide a code example.

---

The `maZ` argument is an implementation feature of Boost.Preprocessor repetition macros. There are three: *z* (used by enum-style functions), *d* (used by while-style functions), and *r* (used by for-style functions). It is only useful when nesting these contructs, as it allows faster preprocessing. If `GENERATE_STRING` was itself calling an enum function, then using `BOOST_PP_ENUM_ ## maZ` would be easier on the preprocessor than just using `BOOST_PP_ENUM` for the nested invocation (but the latter works as well, as long as you don't exceed the compiler's preprocessing limits).

Comment: What role does `maZ` play in `GENERATE_STRING( )`?

Comment: @Olumide Answer expanded.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason why all the arguments begin with `ma`? Also does the case of `z` matter. I'm asking because you've used different cases in your code and explanation .

Comment: @Olumide The case (and spelling) doesn't matter at all, they're macro arguments like any other. `ma` is just my personal coding style for prefixing `m`acro `a`rguments.